# Improve Upload Speed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-4

I've a client who I developed a Rails app for. The app relies on his customers uploading varies of images, files, and pdf size ranges from 1mb to 100mb.

His been telling me that many of his customer are complaining the slowness and unstable upload speed.

I use direct connect to Amazon S3 to handle the upload. I explain to him that it could there are factors that is out of my control in terms of upload speed.

But he insist that there is something we can do to improve upload speed.

I'm running out of ideas and expertise here. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

On the surface, there are two answers -- no, of course there's nothing you can do, the Internet is a best-effort transport, etc., etc.,... and no, there really shouldn't be a problem, because S3 uploads perform quite well.

There is an option worth considering, though.

You can deploy a global network of proxy servers in front of S3 and use geographic DNS to route those customers to their nearest proxy.  Then install high-speed, low latency optical circuits from the proxies back to S3, reducing the amount of "unknown" in the path, as well as reducing the round-trip time and packet loss potential between the browser and the chosen proxy node at the edge of your network, improving throughput.

I hope the previous paragraph is amusing on first reading, since it sounds like a preposterously grandiose plan for improving uploads to S3... but of course, I'm referring to CloudFront.

You don't actually have to use it for downloads; you can, if you want, just use it for uploads.

> your users can now benefit from accelerated content uploads. After you enable the additional HTTP methods for your application’s distribution, PUT and POST operations will be sent to the origin (e.g. Amazon S3) via the CloudFront edge location, improving efficiency, reducing latency, and allowing the application to benefit from the monitored, persistent connections that CloudFront maintains from the edge locations to the origin servers.
>
> https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-cloudfront-content-uploads-post-put-other-methods/

To illustrate that the benefit here does have a solid theoretical basis...

Back in the day when we still used telnet, when T1s were fast Internet connections and 33.6kbps was a good modem, I discovered that I had far better responsiveness from home, making a telnet connection to a distant system, if I first made a telnet connection to a server immediately on the other side of the modem link, then make a telnet connection to the distant node from within the server.

A direct telnet connection to the distant system followed exactly the same path, through all the same routers and circuits, and yet, it was so sluggish as to be unusable.  Why the stark difference, and what caused the substantial improvement?

The explanation was that making the intermediate connection to the server meant there were two *independent* TCP connections, with only their payload tied together: me to the server... and the server to the distant system.  Both connections were bad in their own way -- high latency on my modem link, and congestion/packet loss on the distant link (which had much lower round-trip times, but was overloaded with traffic).  The direct connection meant I had a TCP connection that had to recover from packet loss while dealing with excessive latency.  Making the intermediate connection meant that the recovery from the packet loss was not further impaired by the additional latency added by my modem connection, because the packet loss was handled only on the 2nd leg of the connection.

Using CloudFront in front of S3 promises to solve the same sort of problem in reverse -- improving the responsiveness, and therefore the throughput, of a connection of unknown quality by splitting the TCP connection into two independent connections, at the user's nearest CloudFront edge.

Comment: thanks for this answer. I was considering CloudFront because any other solution is out of my expertise, time and his cost.

Comment: I can't really comment on the capabilities of other services, but to switch from using S3 directly, to using a provider like dropbox, which, itself, appears to use S3, at least as a backing store... I'm not sure what the clear advantage would be.  I answered your question in the context of "improving" rather than "alternatives to" S3 since a question asking for the latter would amount to seeking product recommendations, which would be off topic here.